# How to use a dataframe in a function in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I need to insert the variables of a dataframe into a function in r. The function in question is "y=[1- (x1-x2) / x3]". When I write, and enter the variables manually it works, however, I need to use the random numbers from the dataframe.

````
#Original function
f<-function(x1, x2, x3)
  +{}
f<-function(x1, x2, x3)
  +{return(1-(x1-x2)/x3)}
f(0.9, 0.5, 0.5)```

#Dataframe function
f<-function(x1, x2, x3)
  +{}
f<-function(x1, x2, x3)
  +{return(1-(x1-x2)/x3)}
f(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3, DATA = DF)
````

The first output is ok, however, the second output appears the error message. `Error in f(VMB = VMB, VMR = VMR, DATA = DATA1) : unused argument (DATA = DATA1)` I know I'm not properly inserting the dataframe into the code, but I'm already circling, can anyone help me?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've defined a `DATA` argument to `f`, which is the source of your error

Comment: Maybe see `?with`

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, your problem is that the function doesn't contain a data argument. `R` doesn't know where `x1`, `x2`, `x3` comes from and will only look at through the global environment trying to find them. If these are contained in a data frame, it doesn't know that it should take them from there, and will fail.

For example

```
f <- function(x,y,z)
    1 + (x-y)/z
f(0.9, 0.5, 0.5)
```

will work, because it knows where to retrieve the values. So will

```
x1 <- 0.9
x2 <- 0.5
x3 <- 0.5
f(x1, x2, x3)
```

because it looks through these environemnts, but

```
df <- data.frame(x = 0.9, y = 0.5, z = 0.5)
f(x, y, z) #fails
```

fails, because it doesn't look for them in `df`. Instead you can use

```
f(df$x, df$y, df$z)
with(df, f(x, y, z)) #same
```

which lets R know where to get the variables. (Here i used x, y and z to avoid conflict names)

If this function should always take a `data.frame` and use columns `x1, x2, x3` you could use rewrite it to incorporate this, as below.

```
f <- function(df){
   with(df, 1 + (x1-x2)/x3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I actually managed to run it using another format.
```
set.seed(1000)
f<-function(x1, x2, x3)
  +{}
f<-function(x1, x2, x3)
  +{return(1-(x1-x2)/x3)}
f(x2 =  c(runif(100, 0.0, 0.5)), 
  x1 = c(runif(100, 0.5)), x3 = 0.5)
```
That way I was able to run the random numbers in the function and the data came out as expected.

Comment: Now my problem is how to plot the function?

Comment: Depending on what you want to plot, it is just `plot(f( ... ), ...)`. Note however, with 3 inputs you'd have to plot it in 4 dimensions, to plot input against output. Once you find the fourth dimension let us know. Alternatively use colours or scatter plot. :-)